# save css files at browser for future use

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Is there any way to save the css files of my site that are loaded with the  tag at users' browsers for future use. I mean that I do not want the users to reload the css files each time they visit my site cause it makes the site slower. Can I achive this with html, javascript or php?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: That is usually done anyway. It is called 'caching'. nothing you have to do!

Comment: Kinda happens already. You would have to go out of your way for it to not happen.

Comment: Look at `cache-control`, if the browser respects it, you will have less traffic.

Comment: Is it happening in any cases? I mean all browsers and all user settings?

Comment: Well, you cannot force anyone remote to do something you want him to do. But since it is the standard I'd say it happens in 99.99% of all cases, yes.

Comment: @DaveChen Where is cache-control ?

Comment: @arkascha: You can force them to download an image xD, but yeah I get your message. You can't force them to remember the files.

Comment: Should I remove this question or it is ok?

Comment: `cache-control` is a header you can use for a more fine grained cache control. However it does not help in your case, since caching is already done. It is usually used for the other way 'round: if you want to _prevent_ your files from being cached.

Comment: +1, arkascha, mistake on my part. I meant to say `.htaccess`. Look at [this](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html).

Comment: No, actually you cannot force anyone to download a pic. Only if you stand behind his desk and threaten to hit him, maybe. Otherwise it is up to him if he actually does click a link or not...

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to leverage browser caching, as can be read [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching).

How you can do this is by editing your `.htaccess` file like so (example):

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

As you can see, with this code css files will be cached for 1 month.

Be careful setting your times, because the browser will not reload the file unless the time has expired or the name of the file has changed. An easy way to circumvent this would be to use versions in your file like so: `main.css?v=1.0`. The upside of this is you don't have to rename your files everytime, but downside is most proxies don't cache resources with a "?" in the url.